# Combining FEMA Flood Zones to CSV coordinates in QGIS

Tags: qgis, combine

I'm new to QGIS but have to do some combining of data for my thesis. I have successfully imported two datasets. One is the ArcGIS server for Flood Zones in the USA:

(NFHL: https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/public/NFHL/MapServer)

Secondly I've added a .CSV file with coordinates and more variables for real estate properties.

How do I combine these two so that I find the corresponding flood zone hazard per property in my .CSV file (using their lat & long)?

Comment: Try 'Sample raster values' algorithm in processing toolbox.

Comment: @BenW unfortunately that only gives me NULL values in the sample column.

Comment: You could do it with gdallocationinfo, that one may be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have successfully made a point layer from your CSV, you can use the [Join attributes by location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html?location#join-attributes-by-location) tool.

The `input layer` is your points layer, the `join layer` is the Flood Zones layer (which must be the polygon type).

If you use the `within` predicate, attributes from the Floods Zones polygon that the point falls inside will be added to the point's attributes (in a new layer).

Comment: The .CSV is no problem. However the flood zone is a raster layer. Is there a way to still achieve the result I need?

Answer (score 0):

I would love to see a working answer to your question.  I've accomplished this in the past and I don't remember how.  That said, this might be an alternative for you - download the shapefiles for the regions you need from FEMA: https://msc.fema.gov/portal/advanceSearch
Then you don't need to mess with raster analysis/extraction/etc.